# PhpStorm how to change the signature in all files inside a directory

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

I would like to know if it's possible using PhpStorm to change a header signature like this example by another for all files inside directory.

```
/*
 * myfile.php
 * @copyright year 
 * ...
*/
```

Comment: Maybe Copyright plugin can do that (it's bundled) but I have never used it so not sure. Other than that -- Find & Replace in Path using RegEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copyright plugin can surely do that but you will have to define a custom scope for the directory that you need to update. Find more information at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/generating-and-updating-copyright-notice.html and https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/01/managing-copyright-notices-in-phpstorm/ .